# Bind model from jQuery ajax call in webApi controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

I cant manage to send a data object to a webApi controller with jQuery. The call gets to the method that responds but the textValue and FunValues object is null in MyMethod. Ive tried without the [FromBody] and also as a simple string value called textValue. The result is "SUCESS: your string is " without the string sent.

This is my jQuery

```
  $.ajax({

            url: "api/ApiTest/MyMethod",
            method: "POST",
            data: {

                textValue: "This is text"

            },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("SUCESS: " + result);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("error: " + data.responseText);
            }
        });
```

This is the method and class in the apiController

```
  [HttpPost]
    public string MyMethod([FromBody] FunValues values)
    {
        return "your string is " + values.textValue;
    }

    public class FunValues
    {
        public string textValue; 

    }
```

Comment: My question is How to bind the data from the Ajax call to parameters or object in controller. Not how to return data.

Comment: No. The data sent by jquery is null in the method when debugging.

Comment: Apologies. Misread your question

Comment: No problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You might want to use fiddler and check what content type jquery is passing.

Comment: It should be Json?

Answer (score 0):

probably $.ajax is now not used much. So, it was difficult to create an application and try out. Since $.ajax was more used in the era of forms it has some different default properties.

1. $.ajax uses Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; so you need to explicitly set it to application.json
2. You need to explicitly use JSON.stringify, else it is sent like form data.

Following code worked for me.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:49946/api/Values/MyMethod",
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(
                {
                textValue: "This is text"
            }
            ),
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("SUCESS: " + result);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("error: " + data.responseText);
            }
        });
```